# Setup the application in CodeDeploy with Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, load-balancing, aws-code-deploy

While following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-applications-to-amazon-lightsail/), under *Setup the application in CodeDeploy*, it reads

> 7. Under Load balancer uncheck Enable load balancing.
> 8. Click Create deployment group.

Thing is, when I click **Create deployment group**

[image: CodeDeploy Load Balancer]

it shows a warning that "Choose a target group" is required

[image: Choose a target group required]

The documentation doesn't refer the need to create such target group but apparently is a must do. Note that atm I don't have any options in there.

If I switch from "Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer" to "Classic Load Balancer" I then have to choose a load balancer but also no ptions in the dropdown.

[image: Choose a load balancer required]

Considering I just want to create this deployment group, how to create the ( target group OR load balancer )  and how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create the target group and how it should look like?

Target group (TG) and your ALB must exist before you attempt to use them in deployments.

To create TG you have to go to EC2 Console -> Target groups. How it should look like **depends on your application**. What port it is running, what kind of heath check it should be using and so on. There is no setup that will fit all possible use-cases.

But if you don't have per-exisitng TG, then probably you don't have ALB as well. Thus, maybe you don't need them at all. They are **not required** for CodeDeploy to work.

---

### Edit

Tick it off the "Enable Load Balancer" then you won't be required to use one.

[image: Deployment group without load balancer]

If you read carefully what is mentioned there in step 7, it says

> Under Load balancer **uncheck** Enable load balancing.

So just uncheck it and you're good to click the "Create deployment group" button

[image: Deployment group created]

Comment: Thank you Marcin. Just updated the question... I'm not able to create the "deployment group" without them unless I change the Load balancer to "Classic load balancer" and then this requires to select a Load balancer from the dropdown and none exists.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Can you tick off the "Enable load balancing" option? If you tick it off, you should be required to use one.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Just noticed now it says in the documentation «Under Load balancer **uncheck** Enable load balancing.».